# Why is there an empty result while scraping a Exchange Rate table?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to scrape Korea Exchange Rate by using http://www.smbs.biz/ExRate/StdExRate.jsp this website.

Daily exchange rate is provided by table, So I tried to scrape using `BeautifulSoup`, but it's responses are empty.

Table is like,
[image]

```
url = "http://www.smbs.biz/ExRate/StdExRate.jsp"

html = requests.get(url, verify=False).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

title = soup.select_one('#frm_SearchDate > div:nth-child(17) > table')


title.text
```

> Result :

```
'\n일별 매매기준율\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n'
```

Comment: try printing soup and ctrl-f through the resulting html to see if thetable you're looking for has been rendered already

Answer (score 0):

*Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are there.*

---

Data is loaded via XHR request and table is rendered dynamically by JavaScript, That is why you won't get the table with `BeautifulSoup` cause it could not find it in response of your request.

There are option to get it anyway:

- check your browser dev tools on XHR tab to locate the api and pull part of info from there.
- use `selenium` to get `driver.page_source` with whole table from the 'browser like'rendered version of website.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.smbs.biz/ExRate/StdExRate_xml.jsp?arr_value=USD_2023-01-12_2023-02-03'
soup=BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

{s.get('label'):s.get('value') for s in soup.select('set')}
```

##### Output

```
{'23.01.12': '1245.3',
 '23.01.13': '1244.6',
 '23.01.16': '1240.6',
 '23.01.17': '1234',
 '23.01.18': '1238.5',
 '23.01.19': '1239.8',
 '23.01.20': '1236',
 '23.01.25': '1234.4',
 '23.01.26': '1233.4',
 '23.01.27': '1231.4',
 '23.01.30': '1230.2',
 '23.01.31': '1228.7',
 '23.02.01': '1230.8',
 '23.02.02': '1231.4',
 '23.02.03': '1219.3'}
```